# How are themes like this done?

Tags: user-interface, installation, themes, nsis

Some Chinese programs have installers made with NSIS.

For example, 25PP's PP Helper uses NSIS, but it doesn't look anything like a normal installer.

I'm interested in how installers like these are created and themed.

If you need it, you can find what I'm referring to at http://pro.25pp.com/ppwin; the green button should download the file.

Thanks.

Comment: Posting a screenshot would help...

Answer (score 1):

In general you can create your own UI using the resource editor of your choice (e.g. [XN Resource Editor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/XN-Resource-Editor.shtml), [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)). For a more convenient solution, have a look at the commercial [Graphical Installer](http://www.graphical-installer.com/).

Comment: This really just looks like the free "Experience UI". I'm looking for a more simplified installer like the one in the main post.